# Drop down doesn't get cleared jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a grid view where records are displayed. When the user click the edit button a modal form gets displayed and the user can make changes to the selected record. As part of the form there is a drop down with different user roles. The drop down specifies the current user role the record is linked to.

I have 2 problems:
 1. When i view a record and see the user role in the drop down that role doesn't get cleared from the drop down when i close the form. For example when I go and view another record, in the drop the old record's item is still there.

2. I have tried clearing the drop down but another problems occurs. The drop should display the current user role the record is linked to and other available user roles that can be linked to the user to change their user role. When I clear the drop down only the linked user role is displayed and not the other available roles

This is my code:

Edit button

```
<img src="images/edit.png" id="imgBtn" style="width:20px; height:20px" onclick='popup("<%# Eval("UserID") %>","<%# Eval("roletype") %>", "<%# Eval("Username") %>","<%# Eval("Password") %>","<%# Eval("Email") %>","<%# Eval("UserRoleID") %>")'></>
```

jQuery

```
function popup(idn, roletype, un, ps, em, urid) {
        var $dropdown = $("#roletype");

        $("#userid").val(idn);
        $("#UserRoleID").val(urid);
        $dropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(urid).text(roletype));
        $("#usern").val(un);
        $("#pwd").val(ps);
        $("#eml").val(em);
        $("#popupdiv").dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            position: 'fixed',
            width: 1080,
            height: 500,
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
            },
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

The code below is to view in the drop down the other user roles available

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserRoleID, RoleType from tb_UserRoles", con);
    roletype.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    roletype.DataTextField = "RoleType";
    roletype.DataValueField = "UserRoleID";
    roletype.DataBind();
```

Please advise on how I can clear the drop down and display the current user role + the other available user roles. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume your dropdown is populated the first time? If so you shouldn't clear the drop down (unless you repopulate it each time). Instead you can just select the item that is already in the drop down e.g. $dropdown.val(urid);

Comment: This worked fine. I did a mistake of appending it and that caused the problem. Thank you!